# MySQL Python connector TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ciphers'

Tags: mysql-connector-python

I am running into an issue with MySQL python connection.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./expconfig.py", line 176, in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 728, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 228, in _open_connection
    self._ssl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 150, in _do_auth
    ssl_options.get('cipher'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 420, in switch_to_ssl
    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers=cipher)
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ciphers'
```

MySQL server has "ssl_diabled" , so the client doesn't need SSL connection. However it invokes

I have following,

- Python : 2.6.6 MySql Python connector mysql-connector-python-2.1.7
- OS : RHEL 6.6
- MySQL server Server version : 5.7.17-enterprise-commercial-advanced

Code

```
try:
    flags = [ClientFlag.FOUND_ROWS,-ClientFlag.SSL]

    config = {
        'user' : 'ed30_user',
        'password' : 'mypassword',
        'host' : options.remHost,
        'database' : 'config',
        'client_flags': [-ClientFlag.SSL],
        'ssl_disabled' : False
    }

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cur=cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Comment: Since you are using MySQL Enterprise, make use if your Support contract and ask MySQL Support to get this fixed. They are pretty good at getting things escalated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error was that Pythong 2.6.6 has "ssl" module with different method signature than expected by the MysqlConnector version 2.1.7.

The MySQL web https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html had in correct version table

I dropped back to connector version mysql-connector-python-2.0.5-1.el6.noarch.rpm and the error went away.

Comment: FYI, mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el6.x86_64 worked for me when 2.1.7 did not. 2.1.6 is at least part of the 2.1 release. 2.0 is pretty old now.

Answer (score 0):

just set 'ssl_disabled' : True if using config file
or ssl_disabled='True' if your config is in arguments to mysql.connector.connect function